# Horizontal scrolling in Xcode 4 IDE

Tags: xcode4

How to enable horizontal scrolling in the editor view of Xcode 4? The editor is quite different from that of Xcode 3 where the editor would have got horizontal scrollers if the code goes beyond a line's width.

Where as in Xcode 4, the rest of the code comes down as a next line and this IRRITATES ME A LOT!

Thanks,
Raj

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to Preferences -> Text Editing -> Indentation and uncheck Line Wrapping. Like in the screenshot:

[image]